# how to set footer in pdf using python (django with pisa)

Tags: python, django, pisa

I tried to set footer on first page only by using pisa official documentation but it comes in all pages so please suggest how to apply footer on first page of pdf

Answer (score 0):

Kind of code goes like this

```
<head>
   <style>
       @page {
            size: a4 portrait;
            @frame header_frame {           /* Static Frame */
               -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
               left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 50pt; height: 40pt;
            }
            @frame content_frame {          /* Content Frame */
                left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 90pt; height: 632pt;
            }
            @frame footer_frame {           /* Another static Frame */
                -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
                left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 772pt; height: 20pt;
            }
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Content for Static Frame 'header_frame' -->
  <div id="header_content">
    <h3>Company</h3>
  </div>

  <!-- Content for Static Frame 'footer_frame' -->
  <div id="footer_content">(c) - page <pdf:pagenumber>
    of <pdf:pagecount>
  </div>
</body>
```